# Working with google maps api with no internet connection

Tags: google-maps

in my work place we work in a closed network and we have no way of connecting to the internet (Not allowed due to security reasons).

Is there any way to work with the google maps api offline ??

Comment: what api endpoint you going to connect to?

Comment: There's no way.. you need to be able to get mapping tiles from google..

Comment: ThiefMaster -- you deleted an answer I posted suggesting that he could use Leaflet and OSM.  Could you explain why?  I am not trying to get it ressurected, just understand what was offensive about it so I don't do it in the future.  (And I don't know how to ask except with this comment, sorry.)